# JS - Change Hidden Field "Value" Based on Dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm working with the following form. I can't edit the html. This is built in a landing page builder.

```
<select id="how_many_players" name="how_many_players">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1 to 10">1 to 10</option>
<option value="11 to 20">11 to 20</option>
<option value="21 to 30">21 to 30</option>
<option value="31 to 40">31 to 40</option>
<option value="41 to 50">41 to 50</option>
<option value="50+">50+</option>
</select>
<input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" class="hidden" value="$0.00">
```

I'm looking for JS (?) to change the value in the hidden "price" field based on the option dropdown.

Example: option value 1 to 10 = $100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to use a little javascript for that, here I put some code to do that.

I would recommend to not used formatted values as input values

Split data values with display values, only format values to display them, not in your functions or real value data

```js
const select = document.getElementById("how_many_players");
const price = document.getElementById("Price");
const formattedValue = document.getElementById("formattedValue");

select.addEventListener("change", () => {
    switch (select.value) {
        case "1 to 10":
            price.value = "$100";
            formattedValue.innerText = "$100";
        break;
        case "11 to 20":
            price.value = "$200";
            formattedValue.innerText = "$200";
        break;
        case "21 to 30":
            price.value = "$300";
            formattedValue.innerText = "$300";
        break;
        case "31 to 40":
            price.value = "$400";
            formattedValue.innerText = "$400";
        break;
        case "41 to 50":
            price.value = "$500";
            formattedValue.innerText = "$500";
        break;
        case "50+":
            price.value = "$700";
            formattedValue.innerText = "$700";
        break;
        default:
            price.value = "null";
            formattedValue.innerText = "not valid";
        break;
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="how_many_players" name="how_many_players">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1 to 10">1 to 10</option>
<option value="11 to 20">11 to 20</option>
<option value="21 to 30">21 to 30</option>
<option value="31 to 40">31 to 40</option>
<option value="41 to 50">41 to 50</option>
<option value="50+">50+</option>
</select>
<input id="Price" name="Price" type="hidden" class="hidden" value="$0.00">

<p id="formattedValue"></p>
```

Comment: I have updated the example, check it out. You will have to adapt that example to more customization options. I don't have credentials to that site and I can only give you examples and guidance. Good luck!

Comment: You're my hero!

Answer (score 0):

You get the hidden element through its id and then change the value to the selected option's value like this:

```
document.getElementById('Price').value = document.getElementById('how_many_players').value
```

EDIT:

You probably want to put it into a change event listener for the select, so that the value get's changed, when the select has changed.

```
const selector = document.getElementById('how_many_players')
selector.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('Price').value = selector.value
})
```

Comment: The code in my answer is the example and it is based on your posted code. So, I am not sure what more you need

Comment: That code example you send wrapped in <script> and adding it just before </body> doesn't do anything. Is there something more I'm missing?

Comment: I assumed, that you know how to do the rest. I added code with which the price value gets changed, when the select value changes.